# How to select most 2 last used tags?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT count(*) cnt, * FROM articles_tag
        GROUP BY tag_id
) x

ORDER BY cnt
LIMIT 2
```

But it throws a syntax error in the first line near `(`. How can I fix it?

---

I want to select the 2 last tags which are most used.

```
// articles_tag
+----+------------+--------+
| id | article_id | tag_id |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 123        | 4      |
| 2  | 456        | 3      |
| 3  | 789        | 6      |
| 4  | 123        | 3      |
| 5  | 456        | 6      |
| 6  | 987        | 2      |
+----+------------+--------+
```

Expected result:

```
+--------+
| tag_id |
+--------+
| 3      |
| 6      |
+--------+
```

Comment: Hi. your syntax is a mess. what exactly are you trying to do :)

Comment: Please post sample data and desired result

Comment: your question and sample query are so far off. Your title says 20 yet you have limited to 10 and you mention last tags used yet your query is trying to get a count.. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean

```
select tag_id,count(*) as cnt from articles_tag group by tag_id order by count(*) limit 2
```

Comment: Or just `order by cnt desc`

Comment: There should be no `desc`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a subselect, just count the occurrences, order them descendantly and limit the select to 2.

So it would be:

```
SELECT tag_id, COUNT(tag_id) occurrences FROM articles_tag
GROUP BY tag_id
ORDER BY occurrences DESC
LIMIT 2
```